# Is there a way I could simplify the jQuery code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

everyone, I created a group of 4 buttons(in a list) that displays a description for each button beneath it when a user hovers over the buttons. I used jQuery to toggle the classes of the paragraph elements in order to make it work. What I did works perfectly fine but I just wonder is there a cleaner more simplified way I could have implemented the jQuery code, or is it perfectly fine the way it is? I really appreciate your input on this. Thanks in advance.

```js
$('#web').hover(function(){
  $('#web-blurp').toggleClass('show-blurp');
});

$('#design').hover(function(){
  $('#design-blurp').toggleClass('show-blurp');
});

$('#film').hover(function(){
  $('#film-blurp').toggleClass('show-blurp');
});

$('#marketing').hover(function(){
  $('#marketing-blurp').toggleClass('show-blurp');
});
```

```css
body{
  background-color: black;  
}

.hero-container {
  position: absolute; 
  top: 6%; 
  left: 0; 
  right: 0;  
  margin: 18% auto;
}

.hero-content {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.hero-content li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.hero-content a {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin-right: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.hero-content a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.hero-content span {
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 40% 0;
 font-family: Sans-Serif; 
 text-transform: uppercase; 
 font-size: 1.2em;
 font-weight: 400; 
 color: blue;
  
}

.feat-blurp {
  width: 810px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: Sans-Serif;
  font-weight: lighter;
  font-size: 1.3em;
}

.hide-blurp {
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .5s linear;
}

.show-blurp {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity .5s linear;
  animation-name: blurp-up, blurp-fade;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}

@keyframes blurp-up {
  from{ transform: translateY(50px)}
  to{ transform: translateY(0)}
}
@keyframes blurp-fade {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to { opacity: 1; }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="hero-container">
  <div class="btn-list">
    <ul class="hero-content">
      <li><a href="#" class="feat-btn box-one" id="web">
      <span>button 1</span>
      </a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="feat-btn box-two" id="design">
      <span>button 2</span>
      </a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="feat-btn box-three" id="film">
      <span>button 3</span>
      </a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="feat-btn box-four" id="marketing">
      <span>button 4</span>
      </a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="btn-blurps">
    <div class="feat-blurp">
      <p id="web-blurp" class="hide-blurp">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris</p>
      <p id="design-blurp" class="hide-blurp">nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat       </p>
      <p id="film-blurp" class="hide-blurp">reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      <p id="marketing-blurp" class="hide-blurp">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think this question is more suitable for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: oh, I have never heard of this. Is it the same company? It looks very much alike.

Comment: Yes, it belongs to SO

Answer (score 2):

My advice would be to use `-data` attributes on your paragraphs to show the correct one instead of writing one handler for each button. You also wouldn't need individual id's for each button in this way.

```js
$('.feat-btn').hover(function(){
  var id = $(this).data('id');
  $('#' + id).toggleClass('show-blurp');
});
```

```css
body{
  background-color: black;  
}

.hero-container {
  position: absolute; 
  top: 6%; 
  left: 0; 
  right: 0;  
  margin: 18% auto;
}

.hero-content {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.hero-content li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.hero-content a {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin-right: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.hero-content a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.hero-content span {
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 40% 0;
 font-family: Sans-Serif; 
 text-transform: uppercase; 
 font-size: 1.2em;
 font-weight: 400; 
 color: blue;
  
}

.feat-blurp {
  width: 810px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: Sans-Serif;
  font-weight: lighter;
  font-size: 1.3em;
}

.hide-blurp {
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .5s linear;
}

.show-blurp {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity .5s linear;
  animation-name: blurp-up, blurp-fade;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}

@keyframes blurp-up {
  from{ transform: translateY(50px)}
  to{ transform: translateY(0)}
}
@keyframes blurp-fade {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to { opacity: 1; }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hero-container">
  <div class="btn-list">
    <ul class="hero-content">
      <li><a href="#" class="feat-btn box-one" data-id="web">
      <span>button 1</span>
      </a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="feat-btn box-two" data-id="design">
      <span>button 2</span>
      </a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="feat-btn box-three" data-id="film">
      <span>button 3</span>
      </a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="feat-btn box-four" data-id="marketing">
      <span>button 4</span>
      </a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="btn-blurps">
    <div class="feat-blurp">
      <p id="web" class="hide-blurp">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris</p>
      <p id="design" class="hide-blurp">nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat       </p>
      <p id="film" class="hide-blurp">reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      <p id="marketing" class="hide-blurp">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you I appreciate your advice. I am still a novice at jQuery and javascript so would it be too much trouble to ask for an example of your suggestion? Thank you in advance.

Comment: @Will Sure, here is a working example

Comment: Thank you, I truly appreciate it!

Comment: You could also use the `href` of the `a` element instead of the `data` attribute, but good answer nonetheless

Answer (score 1):

You can attach the event with all the anchor element. Inside the event handler function you can check the *id* of the current element and use that to toggle the *class* dynamically (since all the *p* element's `id` ends with with `-blurp`).

Try the following way:

```js
$('.hero-content a').hover(function(){
  $('#' + this.id + '-blurp').toggleClass('show-blurp');
});
```

```css
body{
  background-color: black;  
}

.hero-container {
  position: absolute; 
  top: 6%; 
  left: 0; 
  right: 0;  
  margin: 18% auto;
}

.hero-content {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.hero-content li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.hero-content a {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin-right: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.hero-content a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.hero-content span {
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 40% 0;
 font-family: Sans-Serif; 
 text-transform: uppercase; 
 font-size: 1.2em;
 font-weight: 400; 
 color: blue;
  
}

.feat-blurp {
  width: 810px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: Sans-Serif;
  font-weight: lighter;
  font-size: 1.3em;
}

.hide-blurp {
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .5s linear;
}

.show-blurp {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity .5s linear;
  animation-name: blurp-up, blurp-fade;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}

@keyframes blurp-up {
  from{ transform: translateY(50px)}
  to{ transform: translateY(0)}
}
@keyframes blurp-fade {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to { opacity: 1; }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="hero-container">
  <div class="btn-list">
    <ul class="hero-content">
      <li><a href="#" class="feat-btn box-one" id="web">
      <span>button 1</span>
      </a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="feat-btn box-two" id="design">
      <span>button 2</span>
      </a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="feat-btn box-three" id="film">
      <span>button 3</span>
      </a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="feat-btn box-four" id="marketing">
      <span>button 4</span>
      </a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="btn-blurps">
    <div class="feat-blurp">
      <p id="web-blurp" class="hide-blurp">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris</p>
      <p id="design-blurp" class="hide-blurp">nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat       </p>
      <p id="film-blurp" class="hide-blurp">reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      <p id="marketing-blurp" class="hide-blurp">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Will, you are most welcome:)

Answer (score 1):

If your `id` names stay the same. You could use that and 'construct' the id of the paragraph you want to select and show.

See below

```js
$('.feat-btn').hover(function(){
  const id = $(this).attr('id');
  const paragraph = $(`#${id}-blurp`)
  $(paragraph).toggleClass('show-blurp');
});
```

```css
body{
  background-color: black;  
}

.hero-container {
  position: absolute; 
  top: 6%; 
  left: 0; 
  right: 0;  
  margin: 18% auto;
}

.hero-content {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.hero-content li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.hero-content a {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin-right: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.hero-content a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.hero-content span {
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 40% 0;
 font-family: Sans-Serif; 
 text-transform: uppercase; 
 font-size: 1.2em;
 font-weight: 400; 
 color: blue;
  
}

.feat-blurp {
  width: 810px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: Sans-Serif;
  font-weight: lighter;
  font-size: 1.3em;
}

.hide-blurp {
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .5s linear;
}

.show-blurp {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity .5s linear;
  animation-name: blurp-up, blurp-fade;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}

@keyframes blurp-up {
  from{ transform: translateY(50px)}
  to{ transform: translateY(0)}
}
@keyframes blurp-fade {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to { opacity: 1; }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="hero-container">
  <div class="btn-list">
    <ul class="hero-content">
      <li><a href="#" class="feat-btn box-one" id="web">
      <span>button 1</span>
      </a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="feat-btn box-two" id="design">
      <span>button 2</span>
      </a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="feat-btn box-three" id="film">
      <span>button 3</span>
      </a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="feat-btn box-four" id="marketing">
      <span>button 4</span>
      </a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="btn-blurps">
    <div class="feat-blurp">
      <p id="web-blurp" class="hide-blurp">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris</p>
      <p id="design-blurp" class="hide-blurp">nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat       </p>
      <p id="film-blurp" class="hide-blurp">reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      <p id="marketing-blurp" class="hide-blurp">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your response!